# in which case TreeBasedTable.create().rowMap().get(rowKey) will return an empty map

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, guava

In my project guava tables are used. version is 15.0. somehow in my logs the mapping for particular rowkey is coming empty like `{rowkey={}}` but I am not able to replicate it.
I tried below approaches.

```
Table table = TreeBasedTable.create();
table.put(rowkey, null,null)  // gives compilation error

table.put(rowkey, "",null)    // giving compilation error

table.put(rowkey, null,"")    // giving compilation error

table.put(rowkey, "","")       // printing like {rowkey={=}}
```

Please help how can I get `{rowkey={}}`  if i print table.rowMap() 
i.e map returning from `table.rowMap().get(rowKey)` is empty (not `null`).

Answer (score 0):

`table.rowMap().get(rowKey)` would return a Map, if the map is null, a probably way is there's no key 'rowkey' at all.

```
    TreeBasedTable tbt = TreeBasedTable.create();
    Object object = tbt.rowMap().get("rowkey");
    System.out.println(object);
```

The output is null.

What about this?

```
    TreeBasedTable tbt = TreeBasedTable.create();
    tbt.put("rowKey", "columnKey", "value");
    Map map = (Map) tbt.rowMap().get("rowKey");
    System.out.println(map); // {columnKey=value}
    map.clear();
    System.out.println(map); // output is {}                                                                                                                          System.out.println(table.rowMap()); // in this case also output is {} while it
```

should be {rowkey-{}}
If rowMap().get("rowKey") is not null, it means there really put value into TreeBasedTable. And then something clear the map.

Comment: TreeBasedTable tbt = TreeBasedTable.create();
    Map map = tbt.rowMap().get("rowkey");
    System.out.println(map==null); System.out.println(map.isEmpty());  output is false true

Comment: I tried below 
 Table<String,String,String> table =TreeBasedTable.create();
 table.put("dik", "sam", "agr");
 Map map=table.rowMap().get("dik");
 map.clear();
 System.out.println(table.rowMap()); and the output is {}. means rowkey is also getting removed.